# Nested fields of a select parameter in custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I have an API endpoint that can receive an object's ID or name, but not both. I'm trying to make nesting within the select parameter. When I use the code below, in the scenario, the nested fields don't appear. Am I missing something?

```json
[
    {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "searchBy",
        "label": "Select",
        "options": [
            {
                "label": "ID",
                "nested": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "number",
                        "label": "ID"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Name",
                "nested": [
                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "Name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add the code you're referring to in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the select options (`"label": "ID"` and `"label": "Name"`) are missing the `value` field, so even when you choose one of them, the platform behaves as if nothing was selected and the nested fields remain hidden.

To fix the problem, simply add `"value": "id"` and `"value": "name"` below the corresponding labels, as shown in the following [documentation example](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/other/parameters/select#nested-fields-for-specific-options). Please note, the values do not need to correspond to the nested field names, they just need to be unique within the list of the parent `select` options.

The resulting code will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "select",
        "name": "searchBy",
        "label": "Select",
        "options": [
            {
                "label": "ID",
                "value": "id",
                "nested": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "number",
                        "label": "ID"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Name",
                "value": "name"
                "nested": [
                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "type": "text",
                        "label": "Name"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```